# Content of CS and EIP registers in Win32 apps in Windows 8

Tags: assembly, windows-8, cpu, memory-address, ollydbg

I created two very simple Win32 applications (from Asm source). Both applications contain only a few bytes in the code section, and I also included some differences in the code section so that the OS won't think that the two executables are identical. I opened both executables with OllyDbg.

I would like to understand why the content of the CS and (E)IP registers displayed in OllyDbg are identical in both debug sessions. I always thought that these two registers define the memory location of the code section. (This was the case in DOS and in earlier Windows versions.)

Does OllyDbg see an emulated version of these registers maybe? Any ideas?

Comment: A protected-mode operating system creates a virtual machine for every process, making it look like it owns the entire machine.  The memory for each process is isolated, one process cannot read or write the memory of another.  Segment registers play no role, every process gets the full 4 gigabytes of address space.  Since processes are always loaded at the same address, 0x400000 by default, the CS and EIP registers must necessarily be the same.

Comment: Segment registers did play a role in i386 protected mode. They used to contain a selector (not a random value), and different memory areas could be accessed using different selectors. What I would like to understand is what has changed since i386 processors in protected mode regarding the CS register. I may be wrong, but I don't think that the OS creates a "virtual machine" for every process,  because I think that the instructions in the executable are directly executed by the CPU, and also the registers used are not emulated.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the comments and to provide a direct answer:

As Hans Passant stated already, *something* like a virtual machine is created for each process. But you are right that it doesn't mean that the processor's operations are emulated. (And in fact, modern processors often have a built-in virtualization feature which even allows virtualization software such as VirtualBox or VMware to run the instructions natively, while the "virtual" part is done by the CPU itself, allowing much faster execution speed of virtual machines.)

What's virtualized here is the memory. In [protected mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode), one can access memory using a segment register and a 32-bit offset, but the segment register is just an index into a table which contains a map describing which blocks of virtual memory are mapped into which blocks of real memory. They can even be mapped to nothing but equipped with a special flag which causes the CPU to run an interrupt routine when this memory page is accessed, allowing the OS to transparently page memory out to a file and page it in only when needed. This table itself is however specific to the process, and set up by OS code whenever code of a process is going to run.

This is a feature provided by the processor directly. So, the code *is* run directly on the processor, but memory access is still abstract. (Note that emulation and virtualization are two different, although related, things.)

There are several levels of privileges, called "rings". Most of the time, only two rings are used: Ring 0 (kernel mode) and ring 3 (user mode). Code running in a higher ring has less privileges than code running in a lower ring. This ensures that, for example, the user mode code in a process can't modify the aforementioned memory map table and therefore can't gain access to the memory belonging to other processes. There are special methods (such as the `sysenter` instruction or special interrupt calls) which allow user mode code to "call" into kernel mode code provided by the OS through well-defined entry points, which can do actions which require higher privileges.

Windows uses the same values for the segment registers in all processes, since their meaning is local to the process anyway. And since an EXE file can specify the base address at which it wants to be loaded (using the PE file header) and your two programs probably have the same address specified (the widely used `0x400000` address), the *virtual* memory address they are loaded to will be the same in both cases.

To answer your question: OllyDbg sees the correct values of the registers, the same the process itself sees. But their meaning is different from what it was in earlier days. The offset you see in EIP is a virtual address (VA), and the segment register value is just like an ID whose real meaning you can't see.

You will also notice that most segment registers have the same value. The only one which is really different is `FS` which is set up to have offset 0 point to the [TIB (thread information block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) of the current thread.